# Does it make sense to compare sets (polygons) with different dimensions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, polygons, polyhedra, integer-programming

In the context of integer programming, I am considering 3 different linear models for a given problem. The goal is to determine which formulation is the tightest, that is, the one that gives the least fractional solution when omitting integrity constraints.

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be the polytopes defined by each of these formulations, without integrity constraints, and let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ denote the optimal values of the formulations over $X,Y,Z$, respectively. Assume we are dealing with a minimization problem. I have managed to prove that
$$
z_1 \ge z_2 \ge z_3
$$
in other words, the formulation over polytope $X$ is the tightest.

From there, do the following inclusions hold (or make any sense) ? :
$$
X\subseteq Y \subseteq Z
$$

My guess is that if the same number of variables is used for each formulation, then yes. But if these numbers are different, I am not sure the polytopes are "comparable" (my wording may be incorrect), and perhaps it makes no sense to use the symbol $\subseteq$.

Comment: You should decide what you mean by the dimension of a polytope (not a polygon) $P\subset R^n$: Do you mean the dimension of the smallest  affine subspace in $R^n$ containing $P$? If so, then $P\subset Q$ implies that $dim(P)\le dim(Q)$ and, thus, in your case $2^n\le kn^2\le kn$, i.e. $n=1$, $k\ge 2$.

Comment: The wording may not be right, indeed. And perhaps the problem is ill posed. At the time I wanted to prove that $\min_{ x\in X} f(x) \le \min_{ y\in Y} g(y) \le \min_{ z\in Z} h(z)$. I know for a fact that this holds, but probably it should not be written in terms of inclusions. Also, in my case, $n$ is arbitrarily large, and $k\le n$.

Comment: Yes, without specifying the meaning of dimension your question is un-answerable. The definition that I suggested is the common one.

Comment: If we forget about the dimensions, is it correct to say that $\min_{x\in X} f(x) \le \min_{y\in Y} g(y)\; \Rightarrow \; X \subseteq Y$ ? I think definetly not.

Comment: The hypothesis now makes no sense to me. Maybe you mean $f=g$ and is continuous (or convex, or linear)?

Comment: Yes indeed, $f=g$, and is continuous, and linear! If you are familiar with integer programming, basically the linear relaxation of $f$ over $X$ is "tighter" than over $Y$. But defining $X$ requires more variables than $Y$ (hence the dimension question - which may be irrelevant- in the first place)

Comment: Yes, I am. You should edit your question accordingly (just do not forget the universal quantifier).

Answer (score 2):

Afik, the question is still ill-posed, but here is what I can tell you:

Suppose, $X$ and $Y$ are (closed) convex polytopes in $R^n$ such that **for every** linear function $f: R^n\to R$, we have
$$
\min f|_Y\le \min f|_X.
$$
Then $X\subset Y$. Here $\min f|_Z= \min \{f(z): z\in Z\}$.

A proof of this is quite straightforward. I will prove the contrapositive: If $X$ is not contained in $Y$ then there exists a linear function function
$f: R^n\to R$, such that
$$
\min f|_X < \min f|_Y.
$$

Since $X$ is not contained in $Y$, one of the vertices $v$ of $X$ is not contained in $Y$. Let $C$ denote the convex hull of $X\cup Y$. Then $v$ is still a vertex of $C$.

Given any convex polytope $P\subset R^n$ and its vertex $p$, there exists a linear function $h: R^n\to R$ such that $v$ is the unique minimum point of $h$ on $P$: $h(p)=a$ and $h(q)>a$ for all $q\in P, q\ne p$. Applying this to the polytope $C$ and its vertex $v$, we obtain a linear function $f: R^n\to R$ such that $f(v)=0$ and $f(c)>a$ for all $c\in C$, except $c=v$. Since $v\notin Y$, we get
$$
a=\min f|_X < \min f|_Y. 
$$
qed

It is, however, possible that the question that you had in mind is a bit different:

Suppose that $f_1,...,f_k$ are given defining linear functions of the polytope $X\subset R^n$  (i.e. $X$ is given by a system of linear inequalities $f_i\ge a_i, i=1,...,k$). Suppose that $Y$ is another polytope in $R^n$ such that for each $i=1,...,k$,
$$
\min f_i|_Y\le \min f_i|_X.
$$
Does it follow that $X\subset Y$? This is indeed false even when $n=2$.

The difference between the two questions is that in the first formulation, I am allowed to enlarge the given defining set of functions for $X$.